# How to remove the horizontal scroll bar and extra white space in the right side of the webpage after creating a side navigation bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, responsive-design

Initially my web page was not having that extra white space but after creating a side navigation bar(hamburger icon for devices having screen size less than 700px) i got the extra white space.

i used the code mentioned below for solving the problem ,but it didn't work,

```
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

html, body {
  max-width: 100%;  /*also tried 100vw and 100%*/
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

My Code :-

HTML(with internal Javascript)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Eduford</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css"
    />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@300&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <img src="images\logo.png" class="logo" alt="logo" />
      <nav>
        <div class="nav-links">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark" onclick="close_navbar()"></i>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#footer">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#course">COURSE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact_us">CONTACT</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-bars" onclick="show_navbar()"></i>
      </nav>
      <div class="textbox">
        <h1>World's Biggest University</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat non
          libero, neque sint quis reprehenderit aspernatur, id qui perspiciatis
          doloremque, error eius quae velit dicta odio distinctio? Maiores
          reiciendis in libero nihil quidem. Sapiente officiis quos ratione
          temporibus, quibusdam odit repellendus excepturi odio, rerum provident
          facere officia, quis ab maxime.
        </p>
        <a href="#">Learn More</a>
      </div>
    </header>

    <!-- JavaScript for Side NavBar -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      const nav_links = document.querySelector(".nav-links");
      function show_navbar() {
        nav_links.style.right = "0px";
      }
      function close_navbar() {
        nav_links.style.right = "-400px";}
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:-

```
<style>
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
}

html, body {   /*I thought it will work but i didn't :( */
  max-width: 100vw;     /*also tried 100vw and 100%*/
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.nav-links {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 30px;
}

.nav-links ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
}

.nav-links ul li::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(219, 65, 65);
}

.nav-links ul li:hover::after {
  width: 80%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

header {
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 20px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.509)),
    url(images/banner.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.nav-links a {
  font-family: "Franklin Gothic Medium", "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

.textbox {
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 90%;
  height: 75vh;
  margin: auto;
}

.textbox h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.textbox a {
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 400;
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.textbox a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(219, 65, 65);
  border: 1px solid rgb(219, 65, 65);
  transition: 0.8s;
}

.logo {
  min-width: 150px;
  width: 20%;
}
.fa-solid.fa-bars::before,
.fa-solid.fa-xmark::before {
  display: none;
}

/* Code for small screens or mobile devices */

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .textbox h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }

  .fa-solid.fa-bars::before,
  .fa-solid.fa-xmark::before {
    display: block;
  }
  .fa-solid {
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
  }
  .fa-bars {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 30px;
  }
  .fa-xmark {
    margin: 10px 15px;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  .nav-links {
    z-index: 1;
    width: 60vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgb(219, 65, 65);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -400px;
    transition: 1s;
  }
  .nav-links ul {
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 70px 30px;
    font-size: 75%;
  
  }
  .nav-links ul li {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}
```

Image:-
[Image showing white space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGmjF.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This is a runnable version of your code and as you see there's no white space around it. `*{margin:0;}` did the job well.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
}

html, body {   /*I thought it will work but i didn't :( */
  max-width: 100vw;     /*also tried 100vw and 100%*/
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.nav-links {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 30px;
}

.nav-links ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
}

.nav-links ul li::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(219, 65, 65);
}

.nav-links ul li:hover::after {
  width: 80%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

header {
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 20px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.509)),
    url(images/banner.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.nav-links a {
  font-family: "Franklin Gothic Medium", "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

.textbox {
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 90%;
  height: 75vh;
  margin: auto;
}

.textbox h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.textbox a {
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 400;
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.textbox a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(219, 65, 65);
  border: 1px solid rgb(219, 65, 65);
  transition: 0.8s;
}

.logo {
  min-width: 150px;
  width: 20%;
}
.fa-solid.fa-bars::before,
.fa-solid.fa-xmark::before {
  display: none;
}

/* Code for small screens or mobile devices */

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .textbox h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }

  .fa-solid.fa-bars::before,
  .fa-solid.fa-xmark::before {
    display: block;
  }
  .fa-solid {
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
  }
  .fa-bars {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 30px;
  }
  .fa-xmark {
    margin: 10px 15px;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  .nav-links {
    z-index: 1;
    width: 60vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgb(219, 65, 65);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -400px;
    transition: 1s;
  }
  .nav-links ul {
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 70px 30px;
    font-size: 75%;
  
  }
  .nav-links ul li {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Eduford</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css"
    />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@300&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <img src="images\logo.png" class="logo" alt="logo" />
      <nav>
        <div class="nav-links">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark" onclick="close_navbar()"></i>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#footer">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#course">COURSE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact_us">CONTACT</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-bars" onclick="show_navbar()"></i>
      </nav>
      <div class="textbox">
        <h1>World's Biggest University</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat non
          libero, neque sint quis reprehenderit aspernatur, id qui perspiciatis
          doloremque, error eius quae velit dicta odio distinctio? Maiores
          reiciendis in libero nihil quidem. Sapiente officiis quos ratione
          temporibus, quibusdam odit repellendus excepturi odio, rerum provident
          facere officia, quis ab maxime.
        </p>
        <a href="#">Learn More</a>
      </div>
    </header>

    <!-- JavaScript for Side NavBar -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      const nav_links = document.querySelector(".nav-links");
      function show_navbar() {
        nav_links.style.right = "0px";
      }
      function close_navbar() {
        nav_links.style.right = "-400px";}
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response , yes there is no white around it normally , but there is horizontal scroll bar and on scrolling horizontally there is white space , i want to remove that horizontal scroll bar.I also added an image of that.

Comment: I don't see any horizontal scroll in the runnable codes, are these the codes you are using too? Could you add a  [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: That horizontal scroll bar is visible on devices with screen having max-width 700px.

Comment: I see you have `<style>` at the top of your `CSS` file which when I use it gives me some white space too, could you remove that and try again?

Comment: Oh i didn't saw that '<style>' in my css , i removed it but still horizontal scroll bar and the white space is there.If you don't see the horizontal scroll bar and white space , check the mobile version of the website .Desktop version of the website have no issues ,only the mobile version have issues.

Comment: I tried some mobile screens too but still no white spaces. Are you sure you are using only the same codes as I did in this answer? Could you try the code that I used in [jsbin.com](https://jsbin.com)?